# bada app crashing on device

Tags: bada

Today I've installed Bada SDK and trying first time to build some apps on BADA.
On bada IDE I'm creating a "bada Form Based Application" (File>New>C++/Flash Application Project>bada Form Based Application), when I run this application on bada Emulator Application it works fine but when I run it on my Samsung Wave 578 Device it crashes after starting. 
What could be the problem, could you please help me about this issue ? 
( using latest SDK )

- I've tried to create manifest.xml file with different API versions it didn't solve the issue.
- I've changed bada Build Model to WaveHVGA,WaveWQVGA,WaveWVGA but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: A bit unhelpful, but still - the problem is Samsung, Bada and the entire mess of a toolchain they have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got finally answer from badateam on bada forums.

http://developer.bada.com/badaforum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=bada-cc&messageId=39165&startPage=1&curPage=1

> badateam@ / Oct, 12, 2011 11:49 Post : #3 Sorry for the inconvenience
>   caused. Kindly note that as of now, there is a small issue with
>   previous versions of the APIs with 2.0.x SDK which will be resolved in
>   a couple of days with a IDE patch.

Comment: the IDE updated itself and now my applications are running on the device too. I'm not sure If they've fixed something or I've changed some setting ..